# Updating Codeigniter 1.7.3 to 3.1.7

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to upgrade from CI version 1.7.3 to CI Version 3.1.7. The problem I have is for some unknown reason the User Guide for 3.1.7 DOES NOT even mention upgrading from version 1.7.3 to version 2.0-let alone upgrading from 1.7.3 to version 3.1.7. How can I get a list of changes made from version 1.7.3 to 3.1.7, IF codeigniter's own user' guide does not even MENTION my version?

I do remember reading something about changing CI version 1.7.2 to version 1.7.3, but then, I am not sure if that means I should follow the upgrade steps for 1.7.2?

So, if I am to follow the steps to upgrade from 1.7.2 to 2.0 then what was the point of upgrading to 1.7.3 to begin with? Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wonder why this was downvoted...

Answer (score 1):

This is the [current upgrade paths](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/installation/upgrading.html) on the CI Site. You need to upgrade from 1.7.x to 2.x, then 2.x to 3.x.

Most of it is pretty simple, but you will want to read carefully from 2.2 -> 3, as that has the most changes.

In response to the comment about system folders, in general you are always entirely deleting the existing system folder in your current project, and then putting in the new system folder from the version you are upgrading too. It is important to delete the old one first, not simply replace it, as sometimes files are removed and not replaced in upgrades.

The caveat is that this is only safe if you have used the framework as intended, and not modified any file inside the system folder. If you have, you will still need to do the aforementioned steps, but you will then need to address your previous modification, perhaps by re-hacking the system files.

Comment: Thank you for your response. One small question though. In the upgrade steps for upgrading from 1.7.2 to 2.0.0, it mentions:

"Step 1: Replace all files and directories in your "system" folder except your application folder.

Note: If you have any custom developed files in these folders please make copies of them first."

What exactly are they asking me to do? Is that asking me to use the original "system" folder or the one from the most recent version of CI? I ask cause as well as I am aware there is no 2.0.0 repository, correct?

Comment: I added more info to my answer about system folders. I see they have 2.0.3 available. I looked at the steps, and you should be able to go from 1.7.2 to 2.0.3, just go through all the steps at once in order for each version from 2.0.0 to  2.0.3 https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/tree/v2.0.3